# Two Lists: Choice field (lookup column) in first list should auto-filter column in second list. Help!

Tags: 2013, custom-list, lookup-column, script, sharepoint-list-filter

I have two SharePoint lists on the same site. One list (List A) has a lookup field (called Select Material) that displays the variables in the "Description" column in list (List B).

I have customized the Default New Form page for List A to also display List B in a web part beneath it on the same page. When a user completes the form for a new list entry, there is a drop down field (which is a lookup field, called "Select Material") wherein they must select the description for the item they would like to change. I would like for the Description column List B to automatically filter the based on the "Select Materials" choice in List A. Can this be done?

FYI, I am not a strong script user and I do not have access to PowerApps.

Any help would be much appreciated. Even if the solution is that it cannot be done because the first column is a lookup column.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your needs through the **[Dynamic List Filtering](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-list-filtering-eed5f92e-1716-45d5-9a94-59decb930e42?ns=spostandard&version=16&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=spo160&helpid=spo_dynamiclist&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)** function.

Note: The Lookup column does not support the Dynamic List Filtering function

**For example:**

1.Create the **Choice column** named Materials in the ListA.

[image]

2.Create the **Choice column** named Material Name in the ListB.

[image]

3.Create a **Site page** and add **List web part** to insert ListA and ListB

4.Edit the ListB web part

[image]

5.On the Edit List Web Part windows, turn on the "**Dynamic filtering**" option and select the filter.

[image]

6.Publish page

[image]

Comment: Hello, and thank you so much for getting back to me. I am using SharePoint 2013 on prem (not modern). However I have tried this approach as well as "connected web parts" which I believe are the same - to no avail. I have not been able to make this work at all. Which is why I wonder if the issue is the column type in list A. Not sure if lookup columns can be used for this scenario.